# Compiling linux kernel in arm64 architecture with self extracting like arm

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, arm64

My problem start in adding KASAN (with KCOV and UBSAN an more) feature.. 
Kernel compilation with these features influence on "Image" size (arm64).
My limitation is size of my partition allocated for kernel image (Image),
As I know, in arm (32 bit) there is a way to create self extraction when the kernel load (This is the reason why the kernel image in the architecture called "zImage").

My question is how I can add features to the kernel in arm64 architecture and meet the limitation.

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using U-Boot to load this kernel image, then you could manually compress the Image file and use a uImage wrapper for storage.  With the proper header info, U-Boot would decompress and relocate the Image file just like zImage would.

Comment: Thanks for fast responding,
I know that, unfortunately my boot loader does not U-boot and I cannot change it.
In addition, I did little review on "arch/arm/boot/compress" code and it's not looking very complex.
How come no one has ever developed self decompress for arm64 ?